# Scalable data processing engine in python to use on a laptop?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-flink, apache-beam

There are a ton of tools to process data in python, including [PySpark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/index.html), [Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/), [Apache Nemo](https://nemo.apache.org/), [Apache Flink](https://flink.apache.org/), and more.

I used Beam to write a simple data flow: count the number of shared elements between any pair of documents.  My hope was that it would use disk appropriately to implement `GroupByKey`, but it appears Beam's `DirectRunner` is not designed to be efficient.  It does its operations in memory, meaning as the data gets large, it runs out of memory.

Is there a dataflow processing tool that I can use on my (OS X) laptop, which has 16G of memory? In particular, I think it would have to do grouping and sorting on disk.

I'm having trouble understanding the scaling characteristics of these tools by reading the docs, especially memory scaling.

**EDIT**: Since there was a request for more specificity, assume there is a tab-separated file on disk with two columns: basket id and item id.  That file is 100G or less.  I wish to count how many items each pair of baskets has in common, and put that result to another file with two columns: basket id and count.  Batch computation is fine, preferred even.

Comment: would mapreduce do?

Comment: I don't think there is enough information to really answer this question. It depends a lot on where your data is residing (also laptop, or elsewhere), are you trying to run a streaming or a batch application, how big are the shared elements, how many documents do you need to analyse, what is the file format etc.

Comment: @MartijnVisser Added a specific problem for you.

Comment: @samkart Sure, mapreduce can probably solve this specific problem.